# AjaxResponseText is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="children" checked="checked"/> Children</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="computers" /> Computers</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="cooking" /> Cooking</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="category" value="finance" /> Finance</label>
<button id="b_xml">List Books (XML)</button>
<button id="b_json">List Books (JSON)</button>
```

This is part of my html code.

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("b_xml").onclick=function(){
        new Ajax.Request("books.php", {
            method:"GET",
            parameters: {category:getCheckedRadio(document.getElementsByName("category"))},
            onSuccess: showBooks_XML,
            onFailure: ajaxFailed
        })
    }
    $("b_json").onclick=function(){
            //construct a Prototype Ajax.request object
    }
};

function getCheckedRadio(radio_button){
    for (var i = 0; i < radio_button.length; i++) {
        if(radio_button[i].checked){
            return radio_button[i].value;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

function showBooks_XML(ajax) {
    alert(ajax.responseText);
}

function showBooks_JSON(ajax) {
    alert(ajax.responseText);
}

function ajaxFailed(ajax, exception) {
    var errorMessage = "Error making Ajax request:\n\n";
    if (exception) {
        errorMessage += "Exception: " + exception.message;
    } else {
        errorMessage += "Server status:\n" + ajax.status + " " + ajax.statusText + 
                        "\n\nServer response text:\n" + ajax.responseText;
    }
    alert(errorMessage);
}
```

and This is my javascript code.
It use prototype.js too.

```
<?php
$BOOKS_FILE = "books.txt";

function filter_chars($str) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]*/", "", $str);
}

if (!isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) || $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "GET") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
    die("ERROR 400: Invalid request - This service accepts only GET requests.");
}

$category = "";
$delay = 0;

if (isset($_REQUEST["category"])) {
    $category = filter_chars($_REQUEST["category"]);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["delay"])) {
    $delay = max(0, min(60, (int) filter_chars($_REQUEST["delay"])));
}

if ($delay > 0) {
    sleep($delay);
}

if (!file_exists($BOOKS_FILE)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    die("ERROR 500: Server error - Unable to read input file: $BOOKS_FILE");
}

header("Content-type: application/xml");

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
print "<books>\n";


$lines = file($BOOKS_FILE);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    list($title, $author, $book_category, $year, $price) = explode("|", trim($lines[$i]));
    if ($book_category == $category) {
        print "\t<book category=\"$category\">\n";
        print "\t\t<title>$ti
        tle</title>\n";
        print "\t\t<author>$author</author>\n";
        print "\t\t<year>$year</year>\n";
        print "\t\t<price>$price</price>\n";
        print "\t</book>\n";        
    }
}
print "</books>";
?>
```

and This is php code.

> Freakonomics|Steven Levitt|finance|2006|18.00
> Harry Potter and the Sorceror's Stone|J.K. Rowling|children|1998|19.99
> Breakfast for Dinner|Amanda Camp|cooking|2009|22.00
> Web Programming Step-by-Step|Marty Stepp and Jessica Miller|computers|2009|999.99
> Building Java Programs|Stuart Reges and Marty Stepp|computers|2007|90.00
> Core Java, 8th edition|Cay Horstmann|computers|2007|35.00
> Personal Finance for Dummies|Eric Tyson|finance|2006|14.95
> 21 Burgers for the 21st Century|Stuart Reges|cooking|2010|75.00
> The Four Food Groups of Chocolate|Victoria Kirst|cooking|2005|30.00
> Go, Dog, Go!|P.D. Eastman|children|1961|8.99

This is books.txt

To explain this code briefly
in javascript, It asks to books.php catagory value that only checked radio button in html.
and books.php print values,
when It is succeed, onSuccess, 
showBooks_XML function is called that alert AjaxRequestText
but It only return like this.

I guess, once an alert event has occurred, 
it means that the flow has gone through onSucceed, which means that books.php received Ajaxrequests well.
so I think this isn't ajax problem.
But I can't find where is problem.
pls give me some hint.

Comment: Inspect the ajax request response in developer tools, e.g for google open developer tools, goto network tab and then make your web applicaiton perform the ajax request , find the books.php request in the list of all requests, click on it and inspect the response

Comment: Or even better, install fiddler - then you can inspect all your newtork traffic, but i small warning first, fiddler is addictive and will reveal how much network traffic your computer is doing..